# Is synchronization for variable change cheaper then for something else?

Tags: multithreading, memory-management

In a multi-threading environment, isn’t it that every operation on the RAM must be `synchronized`?

Let’s say, I have a variable, which is a pointer to another memory address:

```
foo     12345678
```

Now, if one thread sets that variable to another memory address (let’s say `89ABCDEF`), meanwhile the first thread reads the variable, couldn’t it be that the first thread reads totally trash from the variable if access wouldn’t be `synchronized` (on some system level)?

```
foo     12345678  (before)
        89ABCDEF  (new data)
        •••••     (writing thread progress)
        89ABC678  (memory content)
```

Since I never saw those things happen I assume that there *is* some system level synchronization when writing variables. I assume, that this is why it is called an ‘atomic’ operation. As I found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7), this problem is actually a topic and not totally fictious from me.

On the other hand, I read everywhere that synchronizing has a significant impact on performance. (Aside from threads that must wait bc. they cannot enter the lock; I mean just the action of locking and unlocking.) Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35303140/1503237):

> `synchronized` adds a significant overhead to the methods […]. These operations are quite expensive […] it has an extreme impact on the program performance. […] the expensive synchronized operations that cause the code to be so terribly slow.

How does this go together? Why is locking for changing a variable unnoticeable fast, but locking for anything else so expensive? Or, is it equally expensive, and there should be a big warning sign when using—let’s say—`long` and `double` because they always implicitly require synchronization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your first point, when a processor writes some data to memory, this data is always properly written and cannot be "trashed" by other writes by threads processes, OS, etc. It is not a matter of synchronization, just required to insure proper hardware behaviour.

Synchronization is a software concept that requires hardware support. Assume that you just want to acquire a lock. It is supposed to be free when at 0 et locked when at 1.

The basic method to do that is

```
got_the_lock=0
while(!got_the_lock)
  fetch lock value from memory  
  set lock value in memory to 1
  got_the_lock = (fetched value from memory ==  0)
done
print  "I got the lock!!"
```

The problem is that if other threads do the same thing at the same time and read lock value before it has been set to 1, several threads may think they got the lock.

To avoid that, one need atomic memory access. An atomic access is typically a read-modify-write cycle to a data in memory that cannot interrupted and that forbids access to this information until completion. So not all accesses are atomic, only specific read-modify-write operation and it is realized thanks tp specific processor support (see [test-and-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set) or [fetch-and-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetch-and-add) instructions, for instance). Most accesses do not need it and can be a regular access. Atomic access is mostly use to synchronize threads to insure that only one thread is in a critical section.

So why are atomic access expensive ? There are several reasons.

1. The first one is that one must ensure a proper ordering of instructions. You probably know that instruction order may be different from instruction program order, provided the semantic of the program is respected. This is heavily exploited to improve performances : compiler reorder instructions, processor execute them out-of-order, write-back caches write data in memory in any order, and memory write buffer do the same thing. This reordering can lead to improper behavior.

```
1 while (x--) ;         // random and silly loop
2 f(y);
3 while(test_and_set(important_lock)) ; //spinlock to get a lock
4 g(z);
```

Obviously instruction 1 is not constraining and 2 can be executed before (and  probably 1 will be removed by an optimizing compiler). But if 4 is executed before 3, the behavior will not be as expected.

To avoid that, an atomic access flushes the instruction and memory buffer that requires tens of cycles (see [memory barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier)).

2. Without pipeline, you pay the full latency of the operation: read data from memory, modify it and write it back. This latency always happens, but for regular memory accesses you can do other work during that time that largely hides the latency.

An atomic access requires at least 100-200 cycles on modern processors and is accordingly *extremely* expensive.

> How does this go together? Why is locking for changing a variable unnoticeable fast, but locking for anything else so expensive? Or, is it equally expensive, and there should be a big warning sign when using—let’s say—long and double because they always implicitly require synchronization?

Regular memory access are not atomic. Only specific synchronization instructions are expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization always has a cost involved. And the cost increases with contention due to threads waking up, fighting for lock and only one gets it, and the rest go to sleep resulting in lot of context switches.

However, such contention can be kept at a minimum by using synchronization at a much granular level as in a CAS (compare and swap) operation by CPU, or a memory barrier to read a volatile variable. A far better option is to avoid synchronization altogether without compromising safety.

Consider the following code:

```
synchronized(this) {
    // a DB call
}
```

This block of code will take several seconds to execute as it is doing a IO and therefore run high chance of creating a contention among other threads wanting to execute the same block. The time duration is enough to build up a massive queue of waiting threads in a busy system.

This is the reason the non-blocking algorithms like [Treiber Stack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treiber_stack) [Michael Scott](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/papers/1996_PODC_queues.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwirzcXqnJjgAhUBU30KHS7gDk8QFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw3lc-U5GSf6J-dqQubOnLFO) exist. They do a their tasks (which we'd otherwise do using a much larger synchronized block) with the minimum amount of synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

> isn’t it that every operation on the RAM must be synchronized?

No. Most of the "operations on RAM" will target memory locations that are only used by one thread.  For example, in most programming languages, None of a thread's function arguments or local variables will be shared with other threads; and often, a thread will use heap objects that it does not share with any other thread.

You need synchronization when two or more threads communicate with one another through shared variables.  There are two parts to it:

**mutual exclusion**

You may need to prevent "race conditions." If some thread T updates a data structure, it may have to put the structure into a temporary, invalid state before the update is complete.  You can use mutual exclusion (i.e., mutexes/semaphores/locks/critical sections) to ensure that no other thread U can see the data structure when it is in that temporary, invalid state.

**cache consistency**

On a computer with more than one CPU, each processor typically has its own memory cache.  So, when two different threads running on two different processors both access the same data, they may each be looking at their own, separately cached copy. Thus, when thread T updates that shared data structure, it is important to ensure that *all* of the variables it updated make it into thread U's cache before thread U is allowed to see any of them.

It would totally defeat the purpose of the separate caches if every write by one processor invalidated every other processor's cache, so there typically are special hardware instructions to do that only when it's needed, and typical mutex/lock implementations execute those instructions on entering or leaving a protected block of code.